# How can a MFC Unicode application use MySQL ODBC Connector to connect to a latin1 MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, unicode, mfc, odbc, mysql-connector

I unsuccesfully made various attempts to update records, where the name of the row in a MySQL database contains Umlaute (ä,ü,ö,ß). Finally I suspect that Record Field Exchange doesn't handle Umlaute properly. Following are the test cases, that I have tried.

1. Using the MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver (ANSI Driver)
2. Using the MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver (Unicode Driver)
3. Using the MySQL ODBC 5.2a Driver and set charset=latin1 in the Connection string
4. Using the MySQL ODBC 5.2w Driver and set charset=latin1 in the Connection string

In every test case the record succesfully can be read, but updating a record results in the following errors:

1. Unknown column 'EigentÃƒÂ¼' in 'field_list'
2. Server does not support 4-byte encoded UTF8 characters
3. Unknown column 'EigentÃƒÂ¼' in 'field_list'
4. Server does not support 4-byte encoded UTF8 characters

To get more Information, I turned on the ODBC debugging option (found in the MySQL Connector/ODBC Data Source Configuration), which outputs the SQL strings into %TEMP%\myodbc.sql. For the test cases, the driver writes the name like following (myodbc.sql is a ANSI file):

1. SELECT Statement: `Eigentümer`; UPDATE Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`
2. SELECT Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`; UPDATE Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`
3. SELECT Statement: `Eigentümer`; UPDATE Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`
4. SELECT Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`; UPDATE Statement: `EigentÃ¼mer`

I'm surprised that the SELECT works in any case. Do you know how to correctly set up the driver or what I else could do to get it work?

**Server informations:**

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'character_set%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | latin1                     |
| character_set_connection | latin1                     |
| character_set_database   | latin1                     |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | latin1                     |
| character_set_server     | latin1                     |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
8 rows in set (0,00 sec)
```

**Code that is responsible for building the SQL statements:**

```cpp
void invdb::CWDBArtikelRecordset::DoFieldExchange(CFieldExchange* pFX)
{
    pFX->SetFieldType(CFieldExchange::outputColumn);
    RFX_Int(pFX, L"[LNGer]", mWDBArtikel.id);
    RFX_Int(pFX, L"[Gerätetyp]", mWDBArtikel.geraetetyp);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Seriennr]", mWDBArtikel.seriennr);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Inventarnummer]", mWDBArtikel.inventarnummer);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Eigentümer]", mWDBArtikel.eigentuemer);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Meßbereich]", mWDBArtikel.messbereich);
    RFX_Long(pFX, L"[Baujahr]", mBaujahr);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Inbetriebnahme]", mWDBArtikel.inbetriebnahme);
    RFX_Date(pFX, L"[Ende der Garantiezeit]", mWDBArtikel.endeDerGarantiezeit);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Firma]", mWDBArtikel.firma);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Pumpentyp]", mWDBArtikel.pumpentyp);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[PumpeSerNr]", mWDBArtikel.pumpesernr);
    RFX_Long(pFX, L"[AktStation]", mAktStation);
    RFX_Long(pFX, L"[DefaultStation]", mDefaultStation);
    RFX_Int(pFX, L"[IZS]", mWDBArtikel.izs);
    RFX_Date(pFX, L"[daten_vom]", mWDBArtikel.daten_vom);
    RFX_Text(pFX, L"[Schnittstellen]", mWDBArtikel.Schnittstellen);
}
```

**Code that should update the record:**

```cpp
void invdb::updateWDBArtikel(const WDBArtikel& wdbartikel) {
    // CWDBArtikelRecordset is derived from CRecordset
    // GetConnectedDB returns a succesfully connected CDatabase reference
    CWDBArtikelRecordset rs(&conWS.GetConnectedDB());
    rs.m_strFilter.Format(L"LNGer = '%d'", wdbartikel.id);
    rs.Open();
    if (rs.IsEOF())
        throw std::runtime_error("updateWDBArtikel: Not found");
    rs.Edit();
    rs.Set(wdbartikel);
    if (rs.mWDBArtikel.aktStation == AFX_RFX_LONG_PSEUDO_NULL)
        rs.SetFieldNull(&rs.mAktStation);
    if (rs.mWDBArtikel.defaultStation == AFX_RFX_LONG_PSEUDO_NULL)
        rs.SetFieldNull(&rs.mDefaultStation);
    if (rs.mWDBArtikel.endeDerGarantiezeit.GetStatus() != COleDateTime::valid)
        rs.SetFieldNull(&rs.mWDBArtikel.endeDerGarantiezeit);
    rs.Update(); // Results in a CDBException
}
```

Comment: I've got the same problem. I tried to replace these chars before executing the query for odbc, but it's no good solution.